# Image data augmentation and training

Tags: conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, python-3.8

I am using Cats Vs Dogs dataset which contains 2000 images in 2 categories and divided into train and validation directory which can be download [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/mledu-datasets/cats_and_dogs_filtered.zip).

I am trying to use real-time image augmentation to feed into a CNN model using train and validation generators. I am using Python 3.8 and TF2.5. The code is as follows:

```
path_to_imgs = "cats_and_dogs_filtered\\"

# Define the train and validation directory-
train_dir = os.path.join(path_to_imgs, 'train')
val_dir = os.path.join(path_to_imgs, 'validation')

batch_size = 64
IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH = 150, 150


def plotImages(images_arr):
    # function to plot 5 images together-
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 5, figsize=(20,20))
    axes = axes.flatten()
    for img, ax in zip( images_arr, axes):
        ax.imshow(img)
        ax.axis('off')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    
    return None


# Use image augmentation for training dataset-
image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255, rotation_range = 135)

train_data_gen = image_generator.flow_from_directory(
    directory = train_dir, batch_size = batch_size,
    shuffle = True, target_size = (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
    class_mode = 'sparse'
)
# Found 2000 images belonging to 2 classes.


# Validation images need no augmentations-
val_data_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    val_dir, image_size = (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
    batch_size = batch_size)
# Found 1000 files belonging to 2 classes.


# Configure the dataset for performance-
# AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
# val_data_gen = val_data_gen.cache().prefetch(buffer_size = AUTOTUNE)
val_data_gen = val_data_gen.take(batch_size).cache().repeat()



augmented_images = [train_data_gen[0][0][0] for i in range(5)]
plotImages(augmented_images)

# Get a batch of training images and labels-
x, y = next(iter(train_data_gen))

# Get a batch of validation images and labels-
x_t, y_t = next(iter(val_data_gen))

x.shape, y.shape
# ((64, 150, 150, 3), (64,))

x_t.shape, y_t.shape
# (TensorShape([64, 150, 150, 3]), TensorShape([64]))


weight_decay = 0.0005


model = Sequential()
    
model.add(
    Conv2D(
        filters = 64, kernel_size = (3, 3),
        activation='relu', kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.he_normal(),
        strides = (1, 1), padding = 'same', kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(weight_decay),
        input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 3)
        )
    )

model.add(
    Conv2D(
        filters = 64, kernel_size = (3, 3),
        activation='relu', kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.he_normal(),
        strides = (1, 1), padding = 'same', kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(weight_decay)
        )
    )

model.add(
    # AveragePooling2D(
    MaxPooling2D(
        pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)
        )
    )

model.add(
    Conv2D(
        filters = 128, kernel_size = (3, 3),
        activation='relu', kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.he_normal(),
        strides = (1, 1), padding = 'same', kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(weight_decay)
        )
    )

model.add(
    Conv2D(
        filters = 128, kernel_size = (3, 3),
        activation='relu', kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.he_normal(),
        strides = (1, 1), padding = 'same', kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(weight_decay)
        )
    )

model.add(
    # AveragePooling2D(
    MaxPooling2D(
        pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)
        )
    )
    
model.add(
    Conv2D(
        filters = 256, kernel_size = (3, 3),
        activation='relu', kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.he_normal(),
        strides = (1, 1), padding = 'same', kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(weight_decay)
        )
    )

model.add(
    Conv2D(
        filters = 256, kernel_size = (3, 3),
        activation='relu', kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.he_normal(),
        strides = (1, 1), padding = 'same', kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(weight_decay)
        )
    )

model.add(
    AveragePooling2D(
    # MaxPooling2D(
        pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)
        )
    )

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(
    Dense(
        units = 2, activation = 'sigmoid'
        )
    )


# Compile defined model-
model.compile(
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.001),
    # loss=tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits = True),
    # loss = tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
    loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
  )


model(x).shape
# TensorShape([64, 2])

model.predict(x).shape
# (64, 2)

'''
# This is deprecated in favor of model.fit()-
model.fit_generator(
    generator = train_data_gen, steps_per_epoch = len(train_data_gen),
    epochs = 5
    )
'''

model.fit(train_data_gen, val_data_gen, batch_size = batch_size, epochs = 5)
```

Using "model.fit()" gives the error:

> ValueError: `y` argument is not supported when using
> `keras.utils.Sequence` as input.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a typo, it should be `model.fit(..., validation_data = val_data_gen, ...)`

Comment: What's in your validation directory? I tried running your code with the data but theres nothing in validation. Do you manually have to put stuff in there?